# Extract objects (fingerprint and signature) from an image using OpenCV and python

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, opencv3.0

At my website I receive an image contains the user fingerprint and signature, I wan't to extract these two pieces of information.

for example:
[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhZCs.png)

```
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np

def imshow(label, image):
    cv2.imshow(label, image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

#read image
rgb_img = cv2.imread('path')
rgb_img = cv2.resize(rgb_img, (900, 600))
gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(rgb_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

[Gray Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLGp5.png)

```
#canny edge detection
canny = cv2.Canny(gray_img, 50, 120)
```

[canny edge image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJmbt.png)

```
# Morphology Closing
kernel = np.ones((7, 23), np.uint8)
closing = cv2.morphologyEx(canny, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
```

[Morphology Closing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZleKO.png)

```
# Find contours 
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(closing.copy(), cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

# Sort Contors by area and then remove the largest frame contour
n = len(contours) - 1
contours = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=False)[:n]

copy = rgb_img.copy()

# Iterate through contours and draw the convex hull
for c in contours:
    if cv2.contourArea(c) < 750:
        continue
    hull = cv2.convexHull(c)
    cv2.drawContours(copy, [hull], 0, (0, 255, 0), 2)
    imshow('Convex Hull', copy)
```

[Image divided to parts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsESq.png)

Now my goals are:

1. Know which part is the signature and which is the fingerprint
2. Resolve the contours overlapping if exist

P.S: I'm not sure if the previous steps are final so please if you have better steps tell me.

These are some hard examples i may wanna deal with
[image: Hard example 1][image: Hard example 2]

Comment: It seems that color of fingerprint is different so you may use one of the segmentation methods to seperate finger prints. For the signature, You may delete the constant printed writings on it by using some text detection algorithms and then the rest will be signature.

Comment: I wish it was that simple, but the fingerprint color may be variant cording to the inc color the user uses (or if the image is caned by scanner), and the text detection is confused between the handwritten and typed text.

Answer (score 2):

You can use morphology for finger print and signature selecting.
By example:

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('fhZCs.png')
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
img=cv2.bitwise_not(img) #negate image

#color definition
blue_upper = np.array([130,255,255])
blue_lower = np.array([115,0,0])

#blue color mask (sort of thresholding, actually segmentation)
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, blue_lower, blue_upper)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (20,20))
finger=cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

mask2=cv2.morphologyEx(finger, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, kernel)
signature=cv2.compare(mask2, mask, cv2.CMP_LT)
signature=cv2.morphologyEx(signature, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, kernel)

signature=cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=signature)
signature=cv2.bitwise_not(signature)

finger=cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=finger)
finger=cv2.bitwise_not(finger)

cv2.imwrite('finger.png', finger)
cv2.imwrite('signature.png',signature)
```

[image: finger print]
[image: signature]

Comment: Thank you Alex for you efforts, you answer is great but it assumes that the fingerprint and the signature are some kind of blue, but this is not always the case, and I think it fails sometimes because the signature has the shape of ellipse.